# How to use the value of inner xml of an xml node in c#

Tags: c#, xmlnode, innerxml

i have an xmlnode node2.

```
XmlNode node2  = sm.UploadXML(xmlFile);
```

In this node2,node2.innerxml contains the following.

```
 <ContractName>Company Name - yyyy</ContractName><AccountID>123456</AccountID><ContractID>12674</ContractID><NBR>156</NBR><ApplyRateShop>False</ApplyRateShop>
```

now i want to use the value of ContractID.how can i use it?i am doing in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get you the value you require:

```
String contractId = node2.SelectSingleNode("ContractID").InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the InnerXml also contains XML, you can access it using the methods of XmlNode. In your case, you can use [SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a node and then retrieve its value by using the InnerXml property again:

```
var contractIdNode = node2.SelectSingleNode("ContractID");
var contractId = contractIdNode.InnerXml;
```